# Want to configure HTTPS with Tomcat; don't have a registered domain

Tags: https, openssl, certificate, centos7, tomcat8

I'm trying to get HTTPS working with Tomcat.  I'm using Tomcat 8.5.55 on a CentOS 7.7.1098.  I don't have a registered domain to send a CSR to... rather just want to run this on my local host.

I've read multiple sources on the subject and they say to create my own CA.  I did that like so:

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out myCA.key 2048

openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key myCA.key -sha256 -days 1825 -out myCA.pem
```

Then load it on the server:

```
cp myCA.pem /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/

update-ca-trust
```

Then import it into a keystore:

```
keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA

keytool -importcert -alias tomcat -keystore ~/.keystore -file ~/tempcert/myCA.pem
```

Here's what the server.xml looks like:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true">
    <SSLHostConfig>
        <Certificate certificateKeystoreFile="~/.keystore"
                     type="RSA" />
    </SSLHostConfig>
</Connector>
```

But when I try to connect to https://localhost:8443, it just times out (e.g., in Firefox, "The connection has timed out.  The server at localhost is taking too long to respond.)

There isn't any errors in the logs directory either.

Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

server.xml file should contain keystore password.could you please change server.xml as below :-

```
<Connector SSLEnabled="true" acceptCount="100" clientAuth="false"
    disableUploadTimeout="true" enableLookups="false" maxThreads="25"
    port="8443" keystoreFile="yourKeystorefilePath" keystorePass="yourKeystorepassword"
    protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" scheme="https"
    secure="true" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

your keystore file should be imported in keystore with same password.

still any issue, please send me output of below unix command and catalina.out log file from tomcat location to debug more.

1. ps -ef | grep '8443'
2. curl -iv --cert=file https://localhost:8443

One more check, please install this keystore explorer tool from this link (**https://keystore-explorer.org/**)  in your machine and import keystore file in it,once imported it will ask for password(enter correct password).if it will open means keystore file and password is correct.

hope it will resolve your issue.

Comment: Same result... timeout.

Comment: $ ps -ef | grep '8443'
root      8443     2  0 11:50 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/2:0]
dogzilla 22789  6746  0 14:01 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto 8443

Comment: $ curl -iv https://localhost:8443
* About to connect() to localhost port 8443 (#0)
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none

Comment: looks like issue with tomcat startup. please check in catalina.out file logs

Comment: My keystore is in /home/username/.keystore  I'm my server.xml I put ~/.keystore.  When I looked at the log output, after putting your server.xml changes in, I noticed this error line.  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: /opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.55/~/.keystore (No such file or directory).  So I changed it to the absolute path and everything works now.  Thanks!!!